# About the inductive definition of Binary trees

Tags: discrete-mathematics

1.can anyone eplain why the answer is that?Why there is two L in the the induction?How about the right subtree of the Binary tree?
[image]

[image]

Comment: You are ignoring the phrase "where each node has two **identical** subtrees."

Comment: Taken literally, these "trees" are mere chains with every node pointing twice to the next.

Comment: hey guys i updated the questions,thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the empty tree is a tree (with two equal subtrees).

If $L$ is a tree with two equal subtrees, then $L-a-L$ is a tree with two equal subtrees, where $a$ is the root and $L$ are the subtrees.

Comment: Can u  explain the second question for me too,sorry for distributing you!

Comment: In $L-a-L$, the left subtree is $L$, the root is $a$ and the right subtree is $L$ as well.